# Make multiple small rectangles inside big rectangle using svg and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-ng-repeat, rectangles

I have this code where I need to display multiple small rectangles inside a big rectangle and I need to do this entire process multiple times.

here is my data:

```
"data": {
  "rect1": { 
     "a":[10,20],
     "b":[35,10] 
   },
   "rect2": {
     "y":[25,10],
     "z":[55,20] 
   }
}
```

This data should make two rectangles rect1 and rect2 and two rectangles inside each of them a,b and y,z respectively. each small rectangle has start position x and width of that small rectangle for example a starts at x 10 and width=20.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(rect,coords) in data">
    <svg>
    <rect x=1 y=1 width=1000 height=50 style="fill:grey;" />
    <span ng-repeat="coord in coords">
    <rect x={{coord[0]}} y=1 width={{coord[1]}} height=50 style="fill:blue;" />
```

`enter code here`

But this code is not working as I have added ng-repeat line between the two  tags.

[image of what the final result should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2hI0.png)

I made this image in powerpoint so ignore the background.

Comment: I don't get how you want to draw the rectangles. Can you provide an example?

Comment: updated the question to have the image of final result

Comment: Also It will be great if the smaller rectangles can have their names printed as well. But i can do without it too.

Comment: I still don't see the mapping between the coords, which are in a weird format and the drawn rectangles.

Comment: coords are position x and width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close.  You can't use `<span>` inside an SVG. But most of the rest was correct.

Also it is better to use `ng-attr-x="{{value}}` instead of `x="{{value}}`.  Otherwise the SVG parser will throw errors because it doesn't understand the string `"{{value}}"`.

Here is a working example.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.data = {
    "rect1": { 
       "a":[10,20],
       "b":[35,10] 
     },
     "rect2": {
       "y":[25,10],
       "z":[55,20] 
     }
  };

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <ul ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="(rectName, coords) in data">
      <svg id="{{rectName}}" width="100%" height="50">
        <rect x="1" y="1" width="1000" height="50"
              style="fill: lightgrey;" />
        <rect ng-repeat="(label, coord) in coords"
              ng-attr-x="{{coord[0]}}" y="1"
              ng-attr-width="{{coord[1]}}" height="50"
              style="fill: blue;" />
        <text ng-repeat="(label, coord) in coords"
              ng-attr-x="{{coord[0]}}" y="25"
              style="fill: white;">{{label}}</text>
      </svg>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted. Ahhh, it makes so much sense what you just did.